# Is there a way to make an iterator increase every 3 operations?

Tags: c

I need to make an algorithm that calculates a determinant which follows specifics steps.

One of the steps is I have to (on columns) multiply every column with the first element in the matrix  (of size nxn)   and divide it with the first element in the column (Obviously starting from the second column)

For example this 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5yMY.jpg)
transforms in this
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxzmP.jpg)

My idea of code is something like

```
for(i=start+1;i<end;i++)
{for(j=start;j<end;++)
{
    if(matrix[start][start]!=0)
    {
    matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j]*(matrix[start][start]/matrix[start][j])       



    }}}
```

where `start = 0` and `end = n`

But I would like i to increase every 3 operations so I can operate on columns.

Lets put it even more straight forward:

I want j to go down on the colum (while i is not modifying) and when it reaches to end of the column i to increase with one and to operate on the next column.

Comment: Right now, you are increasing `i` by 1. That's what the `++` operator does. So how do you think you might increase it by three? How would you add 3 to `i` *outside* of a loop?

Comment: My idea is that I want j to go down on the colum (while i is not modifying) and when it reaches to end of the column i to increase with one and to operate on the next column.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `i++`, you can use `i += 3` if all you want to do is count by 3s through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by nesting for loops, like you are already doing. For example:

```
int N=3; /* size of matrix */
for (int j=0; j < N; j++) { /* for each column... */
   printf("starting column %d\n", j);
   for (int i=1; i < N; i++) { /* for each row except the first one... */
       printf("  do something i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
   }
}
```

It will end up printing:

```
starting column 0
  do something i=1 j=0
  do something i=2 j=0
starting column 1
  do something i=1 j=1
  do something i=2 j=1
starting column 2
  do something i=1 j=2
  do something i=2 j=2
```